# How to change row size and text size in longtable package to make table fit?

Tags: tables, longtable, fontsize

I have a large table (17 columns, 29 rows). I want to put this in landscape orientation and spread across multiple pages.

```
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \newcommand{\blandscape}{\begin{landscape}}
- \newcommand{\elandscape}{\end{landscape}}
```

```
\newpage
    \tiny
\blandscape
\begin{longtable}{lllllllllllllllll}


Study                     & Study design                    & Groups (n)                                                                        & Study duration (weeks) & CKD Stage              & Mean eGFR (mL/min/1.73 m2)                & Other population characteristics                           & Age (years) & Country   & Intervention frequency/ duration                                                                  & Aerobic                                                                         & Resitance                                                                                                               & Other elements of intervention                                                                                   & Primary Outcomes                                                                 & Secondary Outcomes                                                                                   & Additional laboratory outcomes                                  & Statistically significant findings   in exercise group                                                                                                                                            \\
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
Aoike 2015                & Randomised controlled trial     & Home-based exercise (14); Control   (15)                                          & 12                     & 3-4                    & Exercise = 28.4; Control = 25.3           & Overweight (BMI\textgreater{}25)                           &             & Brazil    & 30-50 minutes, 3 x per week                                                                       & Walking; aiming for VT                                                          & Nil                                                                                                                     & Dietary instruction for all   patients                                                                           & Cardiorespiratory fitness,   physical function                                   & Laboratory measures, BP, body   composition, BMI                                                     & HbA1C, GFR, Hb, albumin                                         & Improved VO2 peak etc, improved   physical funcation; improved eGFR; reduced HbA1c; reduced SBP and DBP                                                                                           \\
Aoike  2018               & Randomised controlled trial     & Home-based group  (12);   Center-based exercise group  (13);   Control group (15) & 24                     & 3-4                    & 26.9                                      & Overweight                                                 & 56          & Brazil    & 40-60 minutes, 3 x per week                                                                       & Moderate (40-60\% VO2max): home-based = walking; centre-based = treadmill       & Nil                                                                                                                     &                                                                                                                  & Physical function; Quality of life;   Sleep; Blood pressure; Laboratory measures &                                                                                                      & eGFR; HbA1C                                                     & Improved BP and HbA1C in both exercise groups. Improved QoL and sleep.   Improved functional capacity and cardiorespiratory fitness (including   VO2peak)                                         \\
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
\end{longtable}
\elandscape

\newpage
```

I'd like to try the following to see if I can make this table fit and be readable.

- Make the text small: I have put `\tiny` before the table, but I want the header row to be a larger text size. I tried `\rowfront {\large}` before the first row but that gave an `! Undefined control sequence` error
- Alter the size of the rows, so they are all higher, to spread the table over more pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and add it to your question.

Comment: Since your columns contain quite lengthy texts, I suggest allowing linebreaks inside of most of the column in order to save space.

Comment: without an example it is harder to test and also you are asking to make it fit without saying how big the page is, and example always helps.

Comment: Having had a closer look at your table code, I seriously doubt, your table will fit onto a page while still keeping the font size at least somewhat readable.

Comment: How man< rows has your table? Possible solution can be transpose your table.

Comment: The rows are no problem using longtable, but there is not a whole lot you can do with the columns.  Even acronyms and footnotes can only save you so much.